# Need help to turn on/off led's after a IR sensor detects something for 3 seconds then turn the led's on/off instantly once nothing is detected

Tags: python

Took a few years off school, so not that great with coding atm just trying to get back into it.

What I need to do is connect a relay module, a 3-wire IR Sensor, and a RED & Green LED to
a Raspberry Pi 3 and make it so that when no one is detected: the RED LED is ON, the GRN LED is OFF

When someone is detected for + 3sec: the RED LED will go OFF, the GRN LED will go ON

I also need to make it so that:
All events are recorded in the Pi csv file, All events are emailed every minute, All events are uploaded to excel, The Relay 1 contacts control the bench LED

The code that I have so far is:

```
Import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
Import time
Import smtplib

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.IN)

while 1:{
    if GPIO.input(7) == True:
    time.sleep(3)
    GPIO.output(16,False)
    GPIO.output(18,True)
    GPIO.output(22,False)

if GPIO.input(7) == False:
    GPIO.output(16,True)
    GPIO.output(18,False)
    GPIO.output(22,True)
}
```

Comment: Seems like a nice project. Do you have a specific question to ask?

Comment: It seems you've taken too much time away from programming. You should check which language you want to write in.